# Messy dates after importing from Excel into R

Tags: r, excel, date, format

I have trouble reading in a date column in the correct format after importing an excel file.

If I format the `Date` column to character, some dates appear messy - like 44655, 44565, 31/03/2022, 30/03/2022...

[image: when the Date column is formatted as character]

However, if I format the `Date` column as a date, there are some `NA` values.

[image: when the Date column formatted in date]

What is the problem? How can I reformat all values in the `Date` column in d/m/y?

Answer (score 0):

This normally occurs if you have entered dates into your excel spreadsheet in multiple formats. I suspect on your excel spreadsheet, sometimes you have the date formatted as a date, and other times, the date is formatted as text. In my experience, its simplest when you have the date entered in excel as text.

If you go in excel, and change the column format to text, you will see the entries that are mixed.

Comment: For reference there is a really handy function in the Janitor package `excel_numeric_to_date` that will handle Excel date numbers. You don't say how you are importing the Excel sheet but readxl has the option to define the column types so you could always import as text and then convert to date within R. The lubridate package does a really good job of this